# How to acquire external analog input in matlab using audio line in?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

For my project I need to get analog input from external circuit and process in the MATLAB. Can I give the analog input into the audio line in?

When I acquire the audio from the microphone, it is working good. Can I use the same commands for this too?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the method you mentioned, but be careful with signal strength. I used to connect a laptop's speaker output to a mic input, and record waveform of mic. The waveform was perfect as long as speaker output fell into the right range (only 1/10 of its max amplitude generated by laptop roughly). So I would suggest you start from very low amplitude, for example 50 mV, and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you.. Is potentiometer enough to reduce the voltage or any other circuit required?